# Left Join returning less rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dataset from a complex query which I've selected into a temp table. Let's call that #mydata

MyData is essentially a list of Client Transactions. Each client could have done multiple transactions

i.e.

```
ClientId    TransactionId

1           123
1           234
1           564
2           897
3           714
5           850
5           963
7           325
8           912
8           375
8           640
```

Now for each row in this table I want to lookup a value from another table by joining on the client id.

The other table contains a rating for each client. And there can only be 1 "approved" rating per client. But there could be other ratings for the client in a non approved state. And it could also be that there is not yet a rating for this client. (The approved status id is 5 - see below).

So I am using a LEFT join from mydataset to ClientRating

I want to end up with the same data that is in #mydata, just with an extra column. I want the same number of rows as #mydata. If there is an approved client rating then put it in the extra column, if there is not, leave it blank

Everything I've tried so far doesn't work

What am I doing wrong?

Without a join I get 2050 rows. With all the joins I've tried I get a different number:

```
--this returns 2050 rows
select  * 
from    #mydata md

 --this returns 2111 rows
    select  * 
    from    #mydata md
    LEFT JOIN   ClientRating b on b.ClientId = md.ClientId AND (ClientRatingStatusid = 5)
--this returns 2111 rows
select  * 
from    #mydata md
LEFT JOIN   ClientRating b on b.ClientId = md.ClientId AND (ClientRatingStatusid = 5 OR ClientRatingStatusid IS NULL)

--this returns 2111 rows
select  * 
from    #mydata md
LEFT outer JOIN ClientRating b on b.ClientId = md.ClientId AND (ClientRatingStatusid = 5 OR ClientRatingStatusid IS NULL)

--this returns 2099 rows
select  * 
from    #mydata md
LEFT  JOIN  ClientRating b on b.ClientId = md.ClientId 
Where  (ClientRatingStatusid = 5 OR ClientRatingStatusid IS NULL)
```

Comment: ClientRatingStatusid is from which table? BTW, change "ClientRatingStatusid = 5 OR ClientRatingStatusid IS NULL" to "ClientRatingStatusid IS NULL OR ClientRatingStatusid = 5", basically order of conditions

Comment: ClientRatingStatusid is in the ClientRating table. Which joins to mydata on the clientid (which is in both tables/datasets

Comment: Just swapped the order to "ClientRatingStatusid IS NULL OR ClientRatingStatusid = 5" -- still gives 2011 rows

Comment: @sllev - order of conditions is irrelevant in this case

Comment: http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/WHERE_conditions_on_a_LEFT_JOIN

Comment: The shown data might be Truncated! This ALSO happens below the X (10000) number of rows when the query becomes to complex. Check the "Truncated data" note below the table! My table of 2999 rows suddenly showed 2567 rows, and it took me a day to find the cause.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### You have essentially three options.

---

**Option 1 - Limit the Joined Result Set**

You can `JOIN` on a subquery to limit the returns per client:

```
select  * 
from    #mydata md
LEFT JOIN  (SELECT clientId, 
           MAX(otherfield) as otherfield, 
           MAX(otherfield2) as otherfield2
           FROM ClientRating
           GROUP BY ClientId) b 
   on b.ClientId = md.ClientId
```

---

**Option 2 - Limit the final result Set**

For this you will need to remove the `SELECT *` and specify fields.  You will also need to `GROUP BY` your ID field:

```
 select  md.Clientid, 
         MAX(field1) as field1, 
         MAX(field2) as field2
 from    #mydata md
 LEFT JOIN   ClientRating b 
   on b.ClientId = md.ClientId 
 WHERE ClientRatingStatusid = 5
 GROUP BY md.cliendid
```

---

**Option 3 - Remove the dupes in your `JOIN`ed table**

If you fix the issues in your data then the original query will work.

---

As a side note, your second condition belongs in a `WHERE` clause not in the `JOIN` criteria.

Comment: no dupes in the joined to table. There is DEFINITELY only 1 approved rating per client. Some clients do have other ratings, but not in an approved status. Some clients are not yet rated so don't have an entry in that table

Comment: @Roonooir - You aren't filtering on the approved status!  This is the issue.  You `JOIN` only on the `ClientID`.

Comment: @Roonooir - Check `SELECT clientID FROM ClientRating WHERE Clientratingstatusid = 5 GROUP BY ClientID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`

Comment: OK - so how do I filter on the approved status? This is exactly what I'm trying to do!

Comment: @Roonooir - check the query I just posted and see if you get any results

Comment: yeah, I've checked that - there is not more than one approved rating per client.

Comment: @Roonooir let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2329/discussion-between-jnk-and-roonooir)

Comment: OK - problem solved - there ARE duplicates. The query tab in Management studio I was using to check for dupes is connected to a different DB to the one I was using for the other query. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The reason is simple: Your join condition matches multiple entries in `ClientRating` for one entry in `#mydata`.

Comment: Yes, well spotted!! So given that there is only 1 approved rating per client in the clientrating table (or maybe no rating, but certainly no more than 1 approved rating), how do I create a query that doesn't return more rows

Comment: I down voted you because your answer wasn't constructive - I can see there's a problem with mis matching conditions - that's why I'm asking for help - I would expect a good answer to suggest a fix - not point out what is plain to see

Comment: @Roonooir: Are you serious? This teaches me to not help you again. In your question it is NOT clear, that you know that this is the reason. Your question sounded like: "Why am I getting more rows then I have in my table?".

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the approved `ClientRatingStatusid`, then why are you also including the unapproved ones (NULL).  If there is no rating of 5, then LEFT JOIN should return a NULL for your query.  Does this work:

```
select  * 
from    #mydata md
LEFT JOIN   ClientRating b on b.ClientRating = md.ClientRating AND ClientRatingStatusid = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

As there are multiple values of the same ClientId, each id will join with the values in the ClientRating table. One of the approaches can be to have a separate table where you only have `Id, ClientId` and the other table to have `ClientId, TransactionId`. Now you can make a join from the `Id, ClientId` table

```
Table1 
Id, ClientId

Table2
ClientId, TransactionId
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem with it...

The parent table has 2050 records, and the child has more -- it's a one-to-many relationship.

The way you filter your final recordset is what results in the 2111 versus 2099.  If you search your parent table for duplicate id's, I bet you find the problem.

```
SELECT * FROM parent HAVING count(id) > 1
```

Comment: no - I have checked - there is only 1 "approved" Rating per client. Some clients have more than one rating but only one of them is approved. Som clients don't yet have a rating

Comment: @Roonooir - how do you know which line is approved

Comment: @JNK it has a ClientRatingStatusid of 5